# How to make a pdf appear as a download option rather than rendering on the browser?

Tags: java, http, rest, jasper-reports, download

I am using Jasper Reports in my project for producing the reports in multiple formats. Although all the code examples run fine, I have ran into a conceptual issue.

I wrote this trivial code which produces a PDF at the browser as a download option:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/basicdbreport")
    @Produces("application/pdf")
    public Response basicDbReport(@Context ServletContext context,
            @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws JRException,
            IOException {
        Connection connection = null;
        byte[] reportBytes = null;
        String reportName = "firstsqlexample";

        File file = new File(path + reportName + JASPER_EXTENSION);

        // check if compiled report exists
        if (!file.exists()) {
            compileReport(context.getRealPath(path + reportName + JRXML_EXTENSTION));
        }

        // input stream for filling the compiled report
        InputStream compiledReportStream = context.getResourceAsStream(path
                + reportName + JASPER_EXTENSION);

        try {
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            reportBytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(compiledReportStream,
                    new HashMap<String, Object>(), connection);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (reportBytes != null) {
            ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(reportBytes);
        }

        ResponseBuilder restResponse = Response.ok();
        restResponse.header("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=firstSQLReport.pdf");
        return restResponse.build();
    }
```

The code runs fine and I get **a download prompt** at the browser. However, when I dug deeper into the Jasper API I found a method [runReportToPdfStream()](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperRunManager.html#runReportToPdfStream%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20java.util.Map,%20java.sql.Connection%29) method which would handle the output stream for me.

The new code looks something like this:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/basicdbreport")
    @Produces("application/pdf")
    public Response basicDbReport(@Context ServletContext context,
            @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws JRException,
            IOException {
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        Connection connection = null;
        String reportName = "firstsqlexample";

        File file = new File(path + reportName + JASPER_EXTENSION);

        // check if compiled report exists
        if (!file.exists()) {
            compileReport(context.getRealPath(path + reportName + JRXML_EXTENSTION));
        }

        // input steam to fill complied report
        InputStream compiledReportStream = context.getResourceAsStream(path
                + reportName + JASPER_EXTENSION);

        try {
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(compiledReportStream, outputStream, new HashMap<String, Object>(), connection);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ResponseBuilder restResponse = Response.ok();
        restResponse.header("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=firstSQLReport.pdf");
        return restResponse.build();
    }
```

The code runs fine but **I do not get any download prompt**, the pdf gets rendered on the browser instead. The response headers are as follows (on the browser):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 21 Aug 2013 05:51:42 GMT
```

**What's the reason that the code now fails to provide a download prompt?** I am not an ace with HTTP but I guess this:

```
restResponse.header("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment; filename=firstSQLReport.pdf");
```

is responsible for the download option. Its nowhere in the response although I did include it in the code. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you are right, `Content-Disposition` is the response header that you need to set to trigger the download action on the client browser.

i think you need to set the response headers first before writing to the response output stream.